# Chrome extension: Permission to use another extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-devtools

I'm working on a chrome extension using React. I would like to use React devtools in dev mode, but it won't appear. I tried adding `chrome://extensions/` in permissions but that isn't a valid one.
Am I missing something to enable this? Also, the Redux devtools do appear once added in the middlewares.

Comment: Not sure how `use React devtools in dev mode` is related to chrome://extensions which is a browser UI page. Can you elaborate or illustrate the question with screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

To work with react-devtools in browser extension  you should use the [standalone version](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools) of react-devtools . Run in your console.

```
$ npm install --g react-devtools
```

add to you manifest.json

```
"content_security_policy": "connect-src ws://localhost:8097"
```

Now run `react-devtools`
Don't forget to reload your extension.

P.S.
If you don't want to install `react-devtools` globally you can run `npm install --save-dev react-devtools` then add to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "react-devtools": "react-devtools"
}
```

And run `npm run react-devtools`